# Routing MyString/MyController1 and MyString

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying with no success to do the following :

url:

```
MyString/MyController1
MyString/MyController2
MyString/MyController3
MyString/
```

For the first three I am using :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "MyString/MyController1", // Route name
                "MyString/MyController1/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "MyController1", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
                new string[] {"Core_Web.Controllers.MyString"}
                );
```

and it works perfectly well. My problem arrives when I try to access *MyString/*.
I have added :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "MyString",
                new { controller = "MyString", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] {"Core_Web.Controllers"}
                );
```

But the call of the url *MyString* gives :

> The resource cannot be found
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /MyString

There is a Controller named `MyString` in `Core_Web.Controllers`.

thanks for your help,

[EDIT]

here is my whole code :

the routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Contabilita",
    "Contabilita",
    new { controller = "Contabilita", action = "Index" },
    new string[] { "Core_Web.Controllers" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Contabilita_Controller", // Route name
    "Contabilita/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
    new string[] { "Core_Web.Controllers.Contabilita" }
    );
```

and the controllers:

```
namespace Core_Web.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerContabilitaBase : ControllerBaseSuper
    {
       ....
    }
    public class ControllerContabilita : ControllerContabilitaBase
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(GetView("Index"));
        }
    }
}

namespace Core_Web.Controllers.Contabilita
{
    public class ImpiantoController : ControllerContabilitaBase
    {
     ...
    }
    public class LottoController : ControllerContabilitaBase
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

but it does not work either. The url with the controller in it works but not the other one. It gives 404.

am I possibly overlooking something else?

[/Edit]

Comment: What is the order of the routes in your files, Can u post all the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following route definitions (in that order):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyString",
    "MyString",
    new { controller = "MyString", action = "Index" },
    new string[] { "Core_Web.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "MyString_Controller",
    "MyString/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "Core_Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Which should give you the following pattern:

```
url                  controller             action
--------------------------------------------------
/mystring            MyStringController     Index
/mystring/my1        My1Controller          Index
/mystring/my1/foo    My1Controller          Foo
/mystring/my2        My2Controller          Index
/mystring/my3        My3Controller          Index
```

Comment: mmhh does  not work. Still trying to twist the routes in every possible way but /mystring does not seem to find MyStringController. ->404

Comment: Try my updated answer. I have removed the default controller constraint from the second route. But I am unable to reproduce your issue. This setup works for me. Ensure that your controller names are correct and that they are defined in the correct namespace: `Core_Web.Controllers`.

Comment: Thx for your help.I have posted the code that seemed relevant to this issue. In the meanwhile, I go back to the abyss of my code to look for the devil...

Comment: I see now :-) `ControllerContabilita` should be `ContabilitaController`. In ASP.NET MVC the convention dictates that all controllers should be suffixed with `Controller`. In your example you have prefixed it with Controller which is the exact opposite. For example your `Impianto` and `Lotto` controllers are properly suffixed.

Comment: No way... I spent 3 hours on this ... I knew, it was a stupid thing, but there... Thanks a lot, I was beginning to try to debug the handling of url in asp.net mvc to understand what the F* it was all about... I owe you a beer!